# Search / Find text for an if statement

Tags: google-apps-script

What I am trying to do is very simple. Unfortunately I can't seem to get it to work in gas.
I'll now embarrass myself and post my latest (of many!) attempts:

```
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // 
      var findVal = ss.getRange("A1").getValue()
      if (findVal.findText("8762", "#N/A"));
      { 
        // do something
      }
      else {
        // do something else
      }
```

I'm just looking to search in a specific cell for the existence of either the number 8762 among a large paragraph of text, or the string #N/A, which will be the only text in the cell. (FYI: the #N/A is not the result of a formula. It's actual text).

And obviously I'm trying to use the result of that "find" as the driver for a conditional statement.

I'm not a dolt in a VBA world, but javascript in a spreadsheet setting can make me feel very foolish at times. Such as right now.

Btw, I did do extensive searching for this solution. Unfortunately everything that I found was part of large convoluted exercises that muddied the waters for me. I just need a basic true/false solution and nothing more.

And yes, I can do the easy half of that...

```
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // 
    var findVal = ss.getRange("A1").getValue()

     if (findVal == "#N/A") { 

   // do something

  }

  else {

   // do something else

}
```

(just to prove that I'm not here looking for a handout... only a helping hand)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nice attempts. It's great to see what you're trying. I think what you're looking for is the String `match` function. This is not specific to Apps Script, therefore you'll not find it in its documentation, but rather on generic javascript docs, e.g. [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

```js
if( findVal.match('8762') || findVal == '#N/A' ) {
  //do something
} else {
  //do something else
}
```

Note that even though we passed a string as a parameter for the `match` function, it is converted into a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). So, it's good you give it a quick study. It may look too complicated but is very useful and rather simple once you get a hold of it.

Another way of doing the above:

```js
if( findVal.match(/8762|^#N\/A$/) ) {
```

And even better, we can guarantee that your number is "alone" and not part of a larger number, as in 187621.

```js
if( findVal.match(/\b8762\b|^#N\/A$/) ) {
```

Comment: Outstanding! Thanks Henrique. Three suggestions, which is 2 more than I could have hoped for! That said, I wonder if I could pick your brain a bit in regard the use of the "pipes", the "caret", and the "\b". I'm sure that everyday javascripters use those without even thinking about it, but those are exactly the types of mysteries that possess no intuitive understanding for those who are not familiar with their use. If you don't mind, of course. Otherwise thank you thank you thank you for your help regardless.

Comment: @5th4x4 - 100% agree with you... regex  is a nightmare to understand but the article that Henrique gave as reference is really helpful...it has allowed me to make a few really nice things work!  So I which you good luck :-)

Comment: The double pipes in the `if` is just a plain [OR clause](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators). The pipe inside the regex also means OR. But note that a single pipe not in a regex (which does not happen on these examples) is a [binary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators), not an OR. The regex special characters are better explained on the MDN link I placed in the answer.

Comment: @Henrique Abreu - Much thanks (again). And I apologize for asking additional questions about things which you had already addresses in that link. I had noticed the link originally, but I became so distracted by the great wealth of information in your response, that the link got lost in all of the relief and excitement. Lesson learned. But thank you for being gracious enough to follow up again.  Between your responses and the link, you have provided me with a tremendous amount of knowledge. Thank you very much for taking the time to help me.

Comment: You're welcome. No need to apologize. I actually was explaining the regex special meanings, but the comment got too big, and the MDN link already has a great explanation, I felt it was better just to highlight that one should read it there :)